# spyder: edit keeps executing in python, not IPython

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, spyder

I am using spyder 3 to run python and am not sure how to get my session to run IPython.

I launch spyder, then click console, and choose "Open an IPython console." I then see in the bottom right quadrant that there's both a Python and IPython console. I make sure that the IPython console is selected.

I then run some code in the editor:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4))
print(df)
```

However, when I hit F5, I get this in return:

```
NOTE: The Python console is going to be REMOVED in Spyder 3.2. Please start to migrate your work to the IPython console instead.

          0         1         2         3
0  0.383901 -1.021537  0.721708 -0.389721
1 -0.779638  0.010816  0.668723 -1.007539
2 -0.918172  1.100903  0.437585 -0.750007
3  0.822504 -2.546719  0.069220 -1.096228
4  1.040603  0.769918 -1.608101  0.279524
5  0.156436  0.518157 -1.278696  0.413262
6  0.211114  0.194401 -0.323856  0.988171
7  0.436519  0.611610 -1.027762  1.546440
8 -0.493041 -0.195899  0.616378 -0.135764
9 -0.355428  0.896633  0.535350  0.189172
```

I want to run in IPython and am not sure what I am doing wrong or missing something basic. Any ideas on how I get this to execute in IPython instead?

FYI I am running windows 10 and installed spyder via anaconda.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installed spyder via anaconda on Win7. Cant reproduce this case.

Things you would like to know:-

They are removing Python consoles from spyder 3.2 and only IPython console will be present.

There is no option currently in spyder to run the code in a dedicated IPython console. This will be added in coming releases.

What you can try:-

Goto IPython console and enter command `runfile("path_to_py_file",wdir="working_directory")`

and press enter.

Comment: I upgraded spyder. Thank you.